# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function, Wagmi, React

Tags: reactjs, wagmi

While it was working fine, I suddenly started getting this error. It is caused by some function in wagmi library: 'wagmi/connectors/walletConnect'. I did not change anything here, have been developing for a couple days then this happend. It is a very specific error so I don't expect anyone to know what the problem is but If anyone have any idea what could be wrong and how I can trace the problem here it would be great. I looked into the source of error but It is just library's modules that takes the parameters and calls other functions and apis.

[image]
[image]

```
import { configureChains, createConfig } from 'wagmi';
import { walletConnectProvider, EIP6963Connector } from '@web3modal/wagmi1';
import { createWeb3Modal } from '@web3modal/wagmi1/dist/esm/exports/react';
import { publicProvider } from 'wagmi/providers/public';
import { alchemyProvider } from 'wagmi/providers/alchemy';

import { MetaMaskConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/metaMask';
import { InjectedConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/injected';
import { WalletConnectConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/walletConnect';
import { CoinbaseWalletConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/coinbaseWallet';

import { ALCHEMY_API_KEY, WEB3_MODAL_PROJECT_ID } from '../config-global';
import { selectedChain } from './chain';

export const getWagmiConfig = () => {
  try {
    const projectId = WEB3_MODAL_PROJECT_ID;

    const { chains, publicClient } = configureChains(
      [selectedChain],
      [
        alchemyProvider({ apiKey: ALCHEMY_API_KEY }),
        walletConnectProvider({ projectId }),
        publicProvider(),
      ],
    );

    const metadata = {
      name: 'NFT',
      description: ' NFT Web3 Modal',
      url: '',
      icons: [''],
    };

    const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
      connectors: [
        new MetaMaskConnector({
          chains,
          options: {
            shimDisconnect: false,
            shimChainChangedDisconnect: true,
          },
        }),
        new WalletConnectConnector({
          chains,
          options: { projectId, showQrModal: false, metadata },
        }),
        new EIP6963Connector({ chains }),
        new InjectedConnector({ chains, options: { shimDisconnect: true } }),
        new CoinbaseWalletConnector({ chains, options: { appName: metadata.name } }),
      ],
      publicClient,
    });

    createWeb3Modal({
      wagmiConfig,
      projectId,
      chains,
      themeVariables: {
        '--w3m-z-index': 1500,
      },
    });

    return wagmiConfig;
  } catch (err) {}
};
```